Does it make sense using nDCG with implicit feedback?
I am comparing multiple offline recommender systems models on an implicit feedback dataset and reporting various metrics.
These models follow the same order with multiple metrics. The best model is always the best model regardless of which metric I decide to use, except in the case of nDCG.
Trying to understand why is that, I realized that perhaps using nDCG with implicit feedback doesn't make much sense. It assumes that the ground truth is ordered, while in fact, is not.
The best models are the ones that just "mimmick" the order of the Ground Truth (GT) by chance (in this case it is sorted by timestamp). But just because a GT user-item pair is on the list before doesn't make it a better fit. Will the result change if I just shuffle the test set? Does this make any sense?
Nevertheless, in recommender systems papers nDCG is always reported, why? I haven't seen this issue mentioned in any of the papers I've read.
